# Error while installing node through brew

Tags: node.js, curl

I tried to install node via brew.

But getting below issue.

brew install node
==> Installing node dependency: icu4c
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/icu4c-54.1.

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: Invalid certificate chain
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
Error: Failed to download resource "icu4c"
Download failed: https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/icu4c-54.1.mavericks.bottle.1.tar.gz
Warning: Bottle installation failed: building from source.
==> Downloading http://download.icu-project.org/files/icu4c/54.1/icu4c-54_1-src.
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
Error: SHA1 mismatch
Expected: 8c752490bbf31cea26e20246430cee67d48abe34
Actual: a2fd3379ea944f6b2f97fb0f79b7b85cb3e14d0b
Archive: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/icu4c-54.1.tgz
To retry an incomplete download, remove the file above.

Please help in resolving this.

Thnks in advance

Comment: no it is not a duplicate. there is an issue with SF server.  check the link .https://twitter.com/sfnet_ops/status/561228107630129153

Comment: Have you tried reaching to this url with safari as it is in the post?

Comment: Was this seriously still the same problem from Jan 30th?

Comment: @BenDiamant ya tried.. its not working and the issue is reported in twitter

Comment: got exactly the same thing for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the package manually from the link, put it in the cache folder (/Library/Caches/Homebrew), then run the command again. This works for me.

(Please see https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/36703 for more details).

Comment: The cache folder is ~/Library/Caches/Homebrew, at least in MacOS 10.14